# Как связать JS со сторонним php скриптом?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Имеется простая форма ввода, JS скрипт, который срабатывает при каждом изменении значения поля и сторонний php скрипт.
Сама форма:
https://jsfiddle.net/L4behp27/

После каждого изменения поля формы, должно происходить обращение к Php скрипту:
https://test.com/test.php
Передавая в качестве параметров значения полей.

Сам скрипт test.php

```
$a = $_REQUEST['a'];
$b = $_REQUEST['b'];
$c = $a + $b;
echo ($c);
```

В результате обращения, получим в ответ значение $с из скрипта. И это значение уже нужно подставить в  с результатом.
Вот именно сам момент с обращением к php скрипту не понятен мне

Comment: гуглить слово [tag:ajax]

Comment: по разному но можно и так к примеру https://jsfiddle.net/xu3vj5Ls/14/

Comment: Во-первых -- понять, что такое архитектура клиент-сервер, во-вторых -- разобраться, что такое HTTP и веб-программирование, в-третьих, понять, что такое формы и как с ними работать, в-четвёртых, как уже говорили, можно начать гуглить слово «Ajax», а ещё лучше «XmlHttpRequest». Вообще, почитать про Ajax можно здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @binliz, не совсем так... Сложение двух чисел - это лишь простой пример. Вычисления в разы сложнее, в виде отдельного модуля на php, поэтому и хотелось бы сделать всё запросом

Comment: так я как раз вам запрос сделал примером fetch(.....